# Difference of org.apache.hadoop.fs

Tags: hadoop

I'm a newbie in Hadoop.
When I read APIs of Hadoop, I saw that package `org.apache.hadoop.fs` in http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/hdfs/r0.22.0/api/index.html has just one class `Hdfs`, while the package in http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.22.0/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/fs/ has many classes and interfaces.
Why is there a difference? If not, what is my mistake?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first link for hdfs directory, while the other for hadoop (core) directory.

Hope this would help

Comment: Thanks! I have guessed it yesterday but I cannot be sure about it.

Comment: Another question, could you show me how to use Hdfs class? As I think, it behaves as a file system, however, I cannot find any example to use it. If coder want to work with HDFS, they use org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem. What is the role of Hdfs class